# Where did Euler publish his formular for the Legendre Symbol?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am working on a thesis and I am using [Euler's criterion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) I am interested in it's origin, so the first publication of it by Euler. I found some references, though I did not find the original work of Euler. It's not linked in mathscinet, either.

Does anybody know where I can see the first usage?

Comment: Well references are in notes 5 and 6 with the link at [The Euler Archive (subject and index)](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//index.html) at the bottom with original and translated papers available (I didn't check)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you, Sir. I checked these two, but I could not find the expression I was looking for. Maybe I just understand the old-fashioned way of writing.

Comment: The [first reference](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/134) (E134en-la.pdf  file) "theorem 4" (cor. 3 page 5) appears somewhat related (take $b=1$ and note that $\displaystyle m=\frac {p-1}2\;$ with $2m+1=p\;$ dividing $a^m-1$ or $a^m+1$).

Comment: (the specific condition $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ appears later, see $48.$ cor. 4 page 12 etc.)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Hm, I really don't see that, but surely I am just to uneducated in that field!

Comment: Compare $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1\pmod{p} \text{ if there is an integer }x \text{ such that }x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ from your [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) with Theorem $11$ p.12 "If $a=f^2\pm(2m+1)\alpha$, and $2m+1$ is a prime number ($p$), then the expression $a^m-1$ is divisible by $2m+1$".  $$-$$Replace $f$ by $x$ and $2m+1$ by $p$ so that $a=f^2\pm(2m+1)\alpha\;$ becomes $a \equiv x^2\pmod{p}$ and do the same for $2m+1|a^m-1$ (btw there is a typo in the proof $f^{2^m}-1$ should be $f^{2m}-1$). Good luck,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I got that now, thank you! Unfortunately I do not find the case for $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = -1$

Comment: See my "first reference" (theorem 4 cor. 3) with $2m+1=p$ dividing $a^m−1$ or $a^m+1$ (for $b=1$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I am not very good in maths, so I don't get it still. But I thank you for your help :)